# How can this throw a NullReferenceException?

Tags: c#, .net, nullreferenceexception

I have the following code:

```
EventLog el1 = new EventLog();
el1.Log = "Application";
el1.Source = "SharePoint Foundation";

el1.WriteEntry("Start", EventLogEntryType.Information);
el1.WriteEntry("SPContext : " + (SPContext.Current == null ? "nothing" : "something"), EventLogEntryType.Information);
el1.WriteEntry("Web ID: " + (SPContext.Current.Web == null ? "nothing" : "something"), EventLogEntryType.Information);
```

The first two `WriteEntry` log just fine, and the second one logs "something".  But the third one will always error out.  Is my brain just fried, or should this never happen?

**PLEASE NOTE:**
The second `WriteEntry` writes "something" to the logs.  This would mean that `SPContext.Current` is not null.

**Update:**

I don't know if it makes a difference but I am running this with elevated privileges using SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges.  Here is my code:

```
        SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
        {
            try
            {
                EventLog el1 = new EventLog();
                el1.Log = "Application";
                el1.Source = "SharePoint Foundation";
                el1.WriteEntry("Start", EventLogEntryType.Information);
                el1.WriteEntry("SPContext : " + (SPContext.Current == null ? "nothing" : "something"), EventLogEntryType.Information);
                el1.WriteEntry("Web ID: " + (SPContext.Current.Web == null ? "nothing" : "something"), EventLogEntryType.Information);

            }
             catch (Exception ex)
            {
                EventLog el1 = new EventLog();
                el1.Log = "Application";
                el1.Source = "SharePoint Foundation";
                el1.WriteEntry(ex.Message + System.Environment.NewLine + ex.StackTrace, EventLogEntryType.Error);
                throw ex;
            }
      });
```

And my stack trace:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Copy_Special.CrossSiteCopy.<>c__DisplayClass1.<Execute>b__0()
```

FYI this code is part of a SharePoint Custom Workflow Action...

Comment: Looks ok. Try to debug and have a look at the values...

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code and checking the values of SPContext and SPContext.Current before executing the last two lines?

Comment: Whereas others have pointed out that the third line will fail if `SPContext` is `null`, I see no way that it can fail if the second line logs "something".  Unless somehow `SPContext` is being destroyed between the two calls.

Comment: Just a hunch, but did you copy and paste the code EXACTLY as it is in your program? Any chance that second line actually is "SPContext.Current = null"?

Comment: Can you please specify error details for third line. Do you get a corelation ID and corresponding entry in SP logs?

Comment: Are you passing el1 to another thread or something? Please paste stack trace!

Comment: @John, unfortunately no.  Good idea though.

Comment: If `Current` and `Web` are properties, then there's possibly code inside them that is causing your NRE.  What's the full stack trace?

Comment: Could this just be a race condition or does this happen every time?

Comment: It happens everytime.  If you have worked with sharepoint you may find this interesting also:  When I start the workflow manually, it runs fine.  When I start it on "document changed" it errors out...

Comment: There might be no Webs, Is this a brand new installation of SharePoint. Also please specify in which context this code is executing? webpart?

Comment: Just FYI: you should just `throw`, not `throw ex`. That's messing up your stack trace.

Comment: @Dan, I gave that a shot but it still throws the same stack trace.

Comment: @Abe: Probably because it's thrown within the same `try` block. I should've phrased that as just a general piece of advice.

Comment: @Abe It makes a **huge difference** actually! There's no `SPContext.Current` under elevated privileges by default!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Update: Completely rewriting my answer according to new clarifications provided in the question and in the comments bellow this answer.*

1. The last line should, at least, read as follows:

   ```
   SPContext.Current == null || SPContext.Current.Web == null ? "nothing" : "something"
   ```
2. `SPContext.Web` property includes a fairly complex logic that under certain circumstances creates a new `SPWeb` instance. Hence, most likely, it may fail with the `NullReferenceException` although that behavior is not documented. In many cases it yields an `InvalidOperationException` as well.
3. Under elevated privileges there's no valid `SPContext.Current`. You have to open the web site *again* to retrieve a `SPWeb` instance that would work under the different security context.

Sample code for correct privilege elevation:

```
// site and web objects working with the current user's privileges
SPSite userSite = SPContext.Current.Site;
SPWeb userWeb = SPContext.Current.Web;

// elevate privileges
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
{
    // get new site and web objects working with elevated privileges
    using (SPSite elevatedSite = new SPSite(userSite.ID)) 
    {
        using (SPWeb elevatedWeb = ElevatedsiteColl.OpenWeb(userWeb.ID)) 
        {
            // …code using elevatedSite and elevatedWeb…
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: SPContext.Current can't be null, because in the second line it writes "something". This wouldn't happen, if SPContext.Current would be null...

Comment: @Daniel, yes exactly.  That is what I was going to say

Comment: I thought that too, but if the line above it prints "something" wouldn't that mean SPContext.Current isn't null?

Comment: Didn't notice. There's a fairly complex logic behind `SPContext.Web`, so the `NullReferenceException` may be caused by its implementation.

Comment: @Ondrej, can you provide a link to what you are talking about?

Comment: @Abe I don't have a specific example or condition when actually it can yield that exception. However, `SPContext.Web` actually has to make a new `SPWeb` instance under some conditions so it seem it may fail although it's not documentation (as everything with SharePoint…). Try simply catching the exception as a workaround.

Comment: @Abe Miessler Updated my answer to reflect your clarifications.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
EventLog el1 = new EventLog();
el1.Log = "Application";
el1.Source = "SharePoint Foundation";
el1.WriteEntry("Start", EventLogEntryType.Information);
var c = SPContext.Current;
el1.WriteEntry("SPContext : " + (c == null ? "nothing" : "something"), EventLogEntryType.Information);
if (c != null) el1.WriteEntry("Web ID: " + (c.Web == null ? "nothing" : "something"), EventLogEntryType.Information);
```